# Ubuntu: Install tor browser & use it with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, tor

How can I install the tor browser to make it useable in Python using Selenium?

I have tried `sudo apt-get install tor-browser`, but I don't know where it gets installed, hence what to put in the `PATH` variable (or in `executable-path`).

My goal is to

1. install Tor browser
2. open Tor Browser with Python Selenium
3. go to a website.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to run the Tor Browser on **MacOS** using Selenium. First, install the Tor Browser by downloading the appropriate package from [here](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en). MacOS will prompt you to move the contents to the Applications folder. Run TorBrowser to see if it works. Leave the TorBrowser running and run the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary= binary)
driver.get("https://check.torproject.org/")
```

On Ubuntu, you can just leave the unzipped folder where it is. Test that TorBrowser works by double-clicking the TorBrowser icon in the folder. After spending a lot of time trying to make Tor work with Selenium on **Ubuntu**, I gave up and concluded that it might be easier to use a different tool specialized for Tor. I tried `tor-browser-selenium` [link](https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium), which worked like a charm. This the code from that repository that worked for me:

```
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver
with TorBrowserDriver("/path/to/tbb/tor-browser_en-US/") as driver:
    driver.get('https://check.torproject.org')
```

Prior to running this above code, you may have to export the environment variable TBB_PATH as follows, otherwise you will get an error stating that TBB_PATH is undefined:

```
export TBB_PATH=/path/to/tbb/tor-browser_en-US/
```

I didn't try Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To see your TorBrowser path and binary open Tor and under the three stripe menu on the top right go Help>Troubleshooting Information

Answer (score -1):

It's

```
sudo apt-get install torbrowser-launcher
```

and `torbrowser-launcher` gets located in `/bin`.

But you can just download the newest version from the official website, unpack and run.

Comment: `Unable to locate package torbrowser-launcher`

Comment: Works in ubuntu 16.04. Anyway, why not download the package from official website of torbrowser?

Comment: Updated the server to the latest version, now installation works. When I try to run it with Python however, I get the error `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 2`